# solving project euler #4 with c++

Tags: c++

Q.A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

this is my code .it worked for 2 digit problem and gave 9009 as answer but it is not working for 3 digit number part.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
bool ispallin(int n)
{
int  reverse = 0, temp;
temp = n;

 while (temp != 0)
 {
  reverse = reverse * 10;
  reverse = reverse + temp%10;
  temp    = temp/10;
  }

  if (n == reverse)
  return true;
  else
  return false;


}
 int main() {
int a[999*999]={0},i,j,no;//0 implies no. at i th position is pallindrome
for(i=100;i<1000;i++)
{
for(j=100;j<1000;j++)
{
    if(a[i*j]==0)//no. is pallin
    {
         if(ispallin(i*j))
         no=i*j;

        else a[i*j]=1;//no. at this pos is not pallindrome
}
 }

}
cout<<no;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "it is not working"?

Comment: Not providing me with the correct Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is very nice, i would add a little bit more comments or maybe meaningful names to the functions but it is good code, the answer isn't what you were looking for because you never made sure that the result is the highest there is.
maybe 700*700 would be a palindrome but then 701*600 would also be a palindrome, i your case once 'i' is bigger it will overwrite the result, even if the polindrom is a bigger one.